# willPresentNotification is not getting called in FCM notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, unusernotificationcenter

I am using FCM notifications and the notification will be triggered from a server.

When I am sending the notification from firebase console the following method is getting called and the notification is displayed in the device .

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler
```

But the same method is not getting called when notification is sent from server.

Here is my code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TabBarViewController.h"

#import "Reachability.h"

@import GooglePlaces;
@import GooglePlacePicker;
@import GoogleMaps;

@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseMessaging;

@import UserNotifications;

#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>


@interface AppDelegate ()<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,FIRMessagingDelegate>

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    // [START configure_firebase]
    [FIRApp configure];
    // [END configure_firebase]

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshCallback:) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
        // iOS 10 or later
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
        UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             // ...
         }];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]




    return YES;
}
- (void)tokenRefreshCallback:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"instanceId_notification=>%@",[notification object]);
    NSLog(@"FCM sire token =>%@",[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]);

    // [FIRInstanceID instanceID] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[notification object]];

    [self connectToFirebase];
}

- (void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging
didRefreshRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)fcmToken{
    NSLog(@"didRefreshRegistrationToken :%@",fcmToken);
}
- (void)connectToFirebase {
    //[FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;

    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@" connected to FCM");
            // you can send your token here with api or etc....
        }
    }];
}

//start notifications
// [START receive_message]
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message 1 ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@" 11 : %@", userInfo);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     //[[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message 2 ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@" 22 : %@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    //new
    //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert + UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
    //    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
     //[[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message 3 ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"33 :%@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey][notification]);

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
   if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive )
    {
        NSLog( @"INACTIVE" );
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    }
    else if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground )
    {
        NSLog( @"BACKGROUND" );
        completionHandler( UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert );
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"FOREGROUND" );
        completionHandler( UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert );
    }
    //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    //completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message  4  ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"44 : %@", userInfo);
    //handle notification
    completionHandler();
}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration 5 token: %@", fcmToken);

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set [Messaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel to YES.
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"Received data 6 message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);
    //[self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {

}

// [END ios_10_data_message]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications 7 : %@", error);
}

// This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
// If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs device token can be paired to
// the FCM registration token.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved 8 : %@", deviceToken);

    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", token);

    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken");
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *strDevicetoken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];
    NSLog(@"Device Token = %@",strDevicetoken);
    [self.defaults setObject:strDevicetoken forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    //.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    //new
    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
    // [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;

//    // for development
//    [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
//
//    // for production
//    //     [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd];
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] APNSToken];

    NSLog(@"FIRMessaging device token retrieved 9 : %@", [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken);
    NSLog(@"FIRMessaging device token retrieved 10 : %@", [FIRInstanceID instanceID].token);
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
//    [[FIRMessaging messaging]disconnect];
//    NSLog(@"disconnecfted from fcm");
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self connectToFirebase];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}
```

In info.plist `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` is set to `NO`

Can some one please let me know How to fix the same.

Comment: I'm not really good with objc. But are you ever reaching the `[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self` line?

Comment: Because if you reach that line then all should be good. What I recommend you try is to see if you can receive a local notification from within the app. If you're able to do such then it means your setup is correct...but there's something wrong with your app settings or possibly the payload/server

Comment: @Honey [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate is calling. In app settings Push notifications is set to ON and background Modes remote Notifications is also Set to Check.

Comment: data = {image:\"\/logo.png\",notification:{\"themeicon\":\"public\\/upload_files\\/theme\\/events.png\",
 "notification_type\":\"Mee\", \"mob_number\ ":\"99999999999\",\"shoutouttitle\ ":\"test\", \"themecolor\ ":\"#6f95f5\", \"theme_Id\ ":\"3\", \"student_Id\ ":\"9\",  \"shoutoutuploadpath\ ":\"\",\"notification_Id\ ":\"107\",  \"shoutoutmessage\ ":\"test msg\", \"shoutouttimeslot\ ":\"\" },\"is_background\ ":false, \"payload\ ":{\"score\":\"5.6\", \"team\ ":\"India\"  }, \"title\":\Events\", \"message\":\"test\",\"timestamp\":\"2017-06-09 8:59:45\"}";from = 608855029366;}

Comment: The same is working for Android.

Comment: 1. post your payload in the question. 2. Did you try to see if you get notifications when you create local notifications?

Comment: Maybe the problem exists with your payload. Take a look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options